# Multiple <blockquote>'s in a row using Markdown Syntax?

Tags: syntax, markdown

I'm trying to include multiple blockquotes using markdown, but I'm stuck on the syntax for closing out the initial blockquote and starting a new one instead of continuing in the current blockquote and adding additional paragraphs...

**=== Current syntax ===**

```markdown
>   Review1
>   -- <cite>Person1</cite>
  
>   Review2
>   -- <cite>Person2</cite>
```

**=== Current result ===**

```html
<blockquote> 
  <p>Review1
    -- <cite>Person1</cite></p> 
  
  <p>Review2
    -- <cite>Person2</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

**=== Wanted result ===**

```html
<blockquote> 
  <p>Review1
    -- <cite>Person1</cite></p> 
</blockquote> 

<blockquote> 
  <p>Review2
    -- <cite>Person2</cite></p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979577/how-can-i-write-two-separate-blockquotes-in-sequence-using-markdown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I write two separate blockquotes in sequence using markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979577/how-can-i-write-two-separate-blockquotes-in-sequence-using-markdown)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Put in a comment

```
>   Review1
>   -- <cite>Person1</cite>

<!>

>   Review2
>   -- <cite>Person2</cite>
```

or a manual line break

```
>   Review1
>   -- <cite>Person1</cite>

<br>

>   Review2
>   -- <cite>Person2</cite>
```

Result

> Review1
>     -- Person1

> Review2
>     -- Person2

Comment: <!> didn't work for me I had to use <!--- -->. The triple dash works with pandoc, but it's not necessary for normal parsing. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/store-comments-in-markdown-syntax)

Comment: Using JSDoc here. The comment method worked for me (with a full HTML comment), but the line break did not.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for Markdown settings that disallow HTML input.