# Comments in Markdown that will be ignored by HTML converter

Tags: html, comments, markdown

I use Markdown for creation and editing of Web Content. I need to keep in my Markdown texts some comments/notes that must NOT be a part of generated HTML, even not as HTML comments. Is there any way for Markdown (or any of its flavors) to have this type of comments "invisible" for converter?

Comment: what converter you are using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store comments in Markdown syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/store-comments-in-markdown-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

It's not straight forward but you may want to have a look at the link below. You may want to use either HTML comment syntax or 'hack' the link syntax to achieve your goal.

[Comments in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/store-comments-in-markdown-syntax)

Comment: You most likely meant to link directly to [the specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/688896), since the approved answer on that page actually adds HTML to the output.