# How to insert a mid-line comment in markdown

Tags: comments, markdown

In markdown comments are made by `<!-- Comment -->`. However when I try to render the following text the comments remain in the render.

```
Summary
---
<!--intro-->
Some proteins <!--- the nanoscopic biological machines running our cells --> are ‘anchored’ into the membranes.
```

*i.e* It appears as:

[image: comment remains in render]

Whereas I am trying to get:

[image]

Does inline commenting exist in markdown? Is this the correct way of doing it (*is there something wrong with the rendering software*)? Or is there a more appropriate way?

---

The parser I used was MacDown v0.42.

Comment: This might depend a lot on the parser you are using. Markdown is not too strictly specified.

Comment: That looks to be the problem. Tried a different parser and the comment is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You used `<!---` instead of `<!--`.

Comment: <!--- should work too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/store-comments-in-markdown-syntax

Comment: Maybe not for your parser (as @kratenko suggested).

Comment: The parser I was using (macports v0.42) doesn't work with either <!--- or <!--. I guess it doesn't currently support inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

The parser I used was MacDown v0.42. It could not remove `<!--` or `<!---`.

As pointed out in the comments other parsers do escape mid-line comments based on these identifiers.

---

I opened [the issue in Github](https://github.com/uranusjr/macdown/issues/276) and an effective workaround, suggested by nkalvi, is to use:

`Some proteins <span style="display:none"> the nanoscopic biological machines running our cells </span> are ‘anchored’ into the membranes.`