# How do I add inline comments in Github Flavored Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to create a gist with an inline comment. I read a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown) which works for putting a comment on it's own line (as shown in the image); however, it doesn't appear to work for inline comments. Is there any way to get inline comments in github flavored markdown?
[image]

```
- [x] some item
- [ ] another item with meta info [//]: # (attempt at meta info as inline comment)


[//]: # (This may be the most platform independent comment)
[//]: # (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown)
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29724376/274466) to the question you linked offers a way...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can also just do this

```
<!--- Comments are Fun --->
```

Remember, markdown is just an easier way to write HTML content.
(note the triple dash)

- some item
- Something with an inline comment

Answer (score 7):

looking more closely at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown/29724376#29724376) a possible workaround for inline comments:

```
- [x] some item
- [ ] another item with meta info [//]: # (attempt at meta info as inline comment)
- [ ] using @ig0774's recomendation [](with an inline comment hidden inside an empty link)

[//]: # (This may be the most platform independent comment)
[//]: # (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown)
[](and another comment down here too using the empty link method)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I fell over this thing `<?put anything &%#$ here ?>`, it seems like a rather robust comment.

It seems to work for stackoverflow as well :-)