# Regex markdown string for key-value pairs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, markdown

My Rails app is retrieving data from a third-party service that doesn't allow me to attach arbitrary data to records, but does have a description area that supports Markdown. I am attempting to pass data for each record over to my Rails app within the description content, via Markdown comments:

```
[//]: # (POST:28|USERS:102,78,90)

... additional Markdown content.
```

I found the `[//]: # (...)` syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/717633) for embedding comments in Markdown, and my idea was to then pass pipe-separated key-value pairs in as the comment content.

Using my example above, I would like to be able to parse the description content string to interpret the key-value pairs. In this case, `POST=28` and `USERS=102,78,90`. If it helps, this comment will always appear at the first line of the Markdown content.

I imagine Regex is the way to go here? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: I think your idea is good, but I suggest *not* using your own artisanal serialization format and instead using something standard like JSON after the `#`. It would simplify both the matching and the parsing significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\G`:

```
(?:^\[//\]:[^(]+\(\K # match your token [//]: at the beginning
|                    
\G(?!\A)\|           # or right after the previous match
)
(\w+):([\w,]+)       # capture word chars (=key)
                     # followed by :
                     # followed by word chars and comma (=val)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sE3rM9/1).

Comment: Can this type of Regexp be performed in a Ruby environment? I'm not sure how to enclose a regexp using `~`s

Comment: @JodyHeavener: Yup, just [**escape the slashes**](http://rubular.com/r/PxjfOnl1Hk)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 2 steps to properly parse this:

First find the comment: `^\[\/\/\]: # \(([^)]*)\)`

- This captures the comment's content.

Then parse the content: `(\w+):([^|]+)` (with the global flag)

- This captures the key and value separately.

Comment: There is really no reason to do this in two separate steps.

Comment: Oh, I see how you're doing it from your answer. I'm a JS developer, which doesn't have that feature. Pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, you could simplify things a lot by using a standard data serialization format like JSON after the `#`. For example:

```
require "json"

MATCH_DATA_COMMENT = %r{(?<=^\[//\]: # ).*}

markdown = <<END
[//]: # {"POST":28,"USERS":[102,78,90]}

... additional Markdown content.
END

p JSON.parse(markdown[MATCH_DATA_COMMENT])
# => { "POST" => 28, "USERS" => [102, 78, 90] }
```

The regular expression `%r{(?<=^\[//\]: # ).*}` uses negative lookbehind to match anything that follows "`[//]: #`".