# R - knitr | .Rnw | How to comment, to avoid compilation errors?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex, rnw

Edit: I am using RStudio

Up till now, while commenting something, I was using `%` symbol. Alternatively, I am just using `Ctrl+Shift+C` shortcut, which results in commenting with `%` or `%'` (or `#` for chunks).

The problem is, even if I comment something, it still often causes compilation errors. Look at the part of screenshot below:

[image: compilation error]

Lines `1` to `23` are fully commented and document starts at line `24`. However, even if parts of the code are commented out and shouldn't affect it, they for some reason still results in errors.

If I move code from lines `24`to`32` at the very beginning of the file, it compiles without problems. I thought that maybe there can't be comments at the beginning of the file, but looks like it's not an issue, as trying things like moving `\documentclass{article}` at the very beginning still results in errors, even though there are less of them.

How can I comment lines, so they won't be calling compilation errors?

Comment: You might have better luck at [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where there are more folks who know a lot about how LaTeX is converted.

Comment: This thread might answer your question: [Comments in Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown)

Comment: The `66.tex` referenced in the console is probably not the same as the code we see, since RStudio will process the `.Rnw` (using pandoc) to produce `66.tex` and then compile it with pdfLaTeX. I think pandoc might insert content before `\documentclass{article}`. Could you provide a more relevant minimal example that we can try within RStudio?

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: there's a possibility that the knitr translator gets confused by having `\documentclass{article}` *not* be the first line in the file.  Try putting it first and see if that resolves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure that all the lines you don't need are "correctely"commented.

Then, i think that you can't put commented code on the top of your document, also avoid to put commented code on your document it's a lousy code.