# Hidden markdown text on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

Is there anything in markdown syntax specifically on GitHub to support hidden text?

I just want to put some to-do notes in `README.md` for myself, not to be visible.

---

**EXTRAS**

As a tribute to the great answer by Tamas, and what's also asked a lot of times, below is an example of how to write foldable sections within MD files:

```xml
<details>
<summary><b>My section header in bold</b></summary>

Any folded content here. It requires an empty line just above it.

</details>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comments in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Just use standard HTML comments:

```
<!-- This is commented out. -->
```

Comment: Works great for PlantUML

Comment: Also works on GitLab. Can be used to include front matter where it normally wouldn't work, like in MR comments, by wrapping the entire front matter in a comment. You will need to custom parse the text though.

Answer (score 5):

(This DOESN'T work on GitHub, which strips out CSS.  But it can work in other Markdown viewers/editors.  The reason I am adding it is because this question came up first when Googling *hidden field markdown*).

You can hide the field using CSS, **if the rendering process respects it and doesn't strip it out**:

Is this worth the hassle, as opposed to using an HTML comment?  Probably not in most cases, though it does allow toggling visibility on and off.

```
#### hidden field with metadata 

<div class="meta_for_parser tablespecs" style="visibility:hidden">{"dataname":"environment","colvar":"varname","colval":"value"}</div>

#### hidden field with metadata
```

##### `glow` a Rust-based terminal viewer

[image]

##### Typora, on macos

[image]

##### Macdown, on macos

[image]

##### But not GitHub

[image]