# Who decides the sizeof any datatype or structure (depending on 32 bit or 64 bit)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, compiler-construction, operating-system

Who decides the sizeof any datatype or structure (depending on 32 bit or 64 bit)? The compiler or the processor? For example, `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes for a 32 bit system whereas it's 8 bytes for a 64 bit system.

I also read that `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes when compiled using *both 32-bit and 64-bit **compiler***.

Suppose my CPU can run both 32-bit as well as 64-bit applications, who will play main role in deciding size of data *the **compiler or the processor***?

Comment: The processor executes machine code, it doesn't decide anything

Comment: Figures that a @StoryTeller would go for the epistemology. :-)

Comment: "Suppose my CPU can run both 32-bit as well as 64-bit applications, who will play main role in deciding size of data the compiler or the processor?" It doesn't matter how many bits your CPU does or doesn't support. Once the application is compiled, the size 'baked into the binary files of the application' _so-to-speak_. If your processor cannot handle the binary, the application cannot run.

Comment: @Prof.Falken - LOL. Well, it seemed appropriate :)

Comment: I am no expert in this area, but isn't it also in the case of WoW64 that it just emulates the 32-bit binaries to 64-bit. So technically it still loads some stuff as 64-bit but then just shows it as 32-bit or something like that to the application?

Comment: @CraigYoung, that is an angle to the question I did not consider. Good comment, it will benefit future viewers of this question.

Comment: Also note the `int` doesn't really need to concern itself much with processor architecture. 32-bit int works fine using half of the available bits in a 64-bit register. Similarly 64-bit int can be fairly easily emulated on 32-bit CPUs. The one thing that isn't so flexible however, is the size of a pointer. _And even then, the **OS** can allow 32-bit apps to run on 64-bit CPU_ NB: Note that the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of int.

Comment: @Neijwiert, what happens is that when 64 bit Windows sees a 32 bit binary, it starts WoW64, which is essentially all the system Windows DLLs, but in 32 bit versions. So a 64 bit install of Windows has two versions of most everything. The same goes for many 64 bit Linux systems, and I guess, Macs.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Right, but it can't one-on-one execute x86 instructions, right?

Comment: @Neijwiert, actually yes, what happens is, which is really cool, is that the 64 bit (Intel/AMD) CPUs can switch mode on-the-fly very efficiently between (legacy) 32 bit and 64 bit mode execution. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/193892

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor --- well explained here I guess.

Comment: Also see [unix and linux data model ilp32 lp64](https://www.google.com/search?q=unix+and+linux+data+model+ilp32+lp64). [The UNIX System -- 64bit and Data Size Neutrality](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html) is very good reading.

Comment: Also related, [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2331751/608639), [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589575/608639)

Comment: @Prof.Falken - In one of your comments you cited [Comments in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/193892). The one that begins with, *[what happens is...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921141/who-decides-the-sizeof-any-datatype-or-structure-depending-on-32bit-or-64bit#comment84848822_48921141)* I don't quite understand the connection.

Comment: size of int is most certainly not necessarily 8 bytes of a 64bit platform. It is for gcc x64, but not even all platforms of the same version of the gcc compiler, let alone other compilers. If you assume this, you will run into trouble. if you need something wide enough for a pointer, there is size_t

Comment: @jww, I saw that you typed <strike>something</strike>

Comment: There is a type for (potentially) holding a pointer, it is spelled `uintptr_t` or something like that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's ultimately the compiler. The compiler implementors can decide to emulate whatever integer size they see fit, regardless of what the CPU handles the most efficiently. That said, the C (and C++) standard is written such, that the compiler implementor is free to choose the fastest and most efficient way. For many compilers, the implementers chose to keep int as a 32 bit, although the CPU natively handles 64 bit ints very efficiently.

I think this was done in part to increase portability towards programs written when 32 bit machines were the most common and who expected an int to be 32 bits and no longer. (It could also be, as user [user3386109 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921141/who-decides-the-sizeof-any-datatype-or-structure-depending-on-32-bit-or-64-bit#comment84849033_48921163), that 32 bit data was preferred because it takes less space and therefore can be accessed faster.)

So if you want to make sure you get 64 bit ints, you use `int64_t` instead of `int` to declare your variable. If you know your value will fit inside of 32 bits or you don't care about size, you use `int` to let the compiler pick the most efficient representation.

<sub>As for the other datatypes such as `struct`, they are composed from the base types such as `int`.</sub>

Comment: Yes, but the compiler also sets the size based on the target processor. So it's the compiler, which uses the information about the processor.

Comment: @Justin, addressed in the part about how the compiler has a lot of lee-way to chose whatever sizes gives the fastest or most efficient results.

Comment: Or 32-bits are used to save memory and improve cache performance. It doesn't take many 64-bit ints to fill up a cache line.

Comment: *"So if you want to make sure you get 64 bit ints, you use long long or int64_t instead of int to declare your variable..."* - Unconditionally using `long long` causes subtle problems on some platforms, like MinGW and Cygwin. OP should check the data model and make the typedef accordingly. If the data model is `LP64` then just use a `long int`.

Comment: @jww, thanks removed `long long`, we don't want to promote anti-patterns. :)

Comment: For GCC it has always been the idea of a nice progression of 8, 16, 32, 64 bit sizes, where in the ancient times int often was 16 bit

Comment: `int64_t` is not required to exist. `long long` is required, and it is always at least 64 bits wide; when the hardware doesn't support it directly the compiler will generate appropriate code.

Comment: `int_fast64_t` and `int_least64_t` are two possible alternatives from `stdint` that *are* guaranteed to exist (and both have unsigned counterparts)

Comment: @PeteBecker There is no guarantee that `long long` is larger than 1 byte.  In practice, it is at least 64-bits wide, just like how in practice `int64_t` exists.

Comment: @CortAmmon -- `long long` is required by the language definition to be at least 64 bits wide. It's a bit hard to find, because it's in the library section. It comes from the C standard, which requires that `LLONG_MIN` must be no greater than -(2^63-1) and that LLONG_MAX must be no less than 2^63-1.

Comment: @PeteBecker Well that's fascinating.  I've never had to cross reference all of those before!

Comment: With a 16-bit `int` "If you know your value will fit inside of 32 bits or you don't care about size, you use `int` to let the compiler pick the most efficient representation." is bad advice.  100s of million of embedded processors each year in 2016 use 16-bit `int`.  Although a program for Linux does not need to worry about that given the OS push for  32_bit `int` or wider.

Comment: @CortAmmon -- for completeness: `char` must be at least 8 bits wide; `short` at least 16; `int` at least 16; `long` at least 32; and `long long` at least 64. Same for `signed char` and all the `unsigned` variants.

Comment: Regarding why `int` is 32 bits in most 64-bits compilers: [64-Bit Programming Models: Why LP64?](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html)

Comment: @chux : Posix requires 32-bit ints and in practise Windows does too.  Limiting oneself to Posix+Windows is often a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: This is largely overlooking the existence of standards (language standards and processor ABIs) which @Art corrently calls out. Compiler writers have very little "leeway" in many areas, such as how big certain data types are "supposed" to be (@gyre has pointed out a couple where they do).

Comment: @MartinBonner Note that most processors in 2017, by far, are not under a Posix nor Windows OS.  Embedded processors are in the billions per year.    True that OP's post is tagged with an OS, yet C and the scope of the title question extend beyond that.

Comment: @chux: Sure.  But the number of processors is not an interesting metric. 
 Most people writing software *are* writing for Posix or Windows (and of those that aren't, quite a lot are writing for embedded processors with 32-bit int)

Answer (score 26):

It's not the CPU, nor the compiler, nor the operating system. It's all three at the same time.

The compiler can't just make things up. It has to adhere to the right ABI[1] that that the operating system provides. If structs and system calls provided by the operating system have types with certain sizes and alignment requirements the compiler isn't really free to make up its own reality unless the compiler developers want to reimplement wrapper functions for everything the operating system provides. Then the ABI of the operating system can't just be completely made up, it has to do what can be reasonably done on the CPU. And very often the ABI of one operating system will be very similar to other ABIs for other operating systems on the same CPU because it's easier to just be able to reuse the work they did (on compilers among other things).

In case of computers that support both 32 bit and 64 bit code there still needs to be work done by the operating system to support running programs in both modes (because the system has to provide two different ABIs). Some operating systems don't do it and on those you don't have a choice.

[1] ABI stands for Application Binary Interface. It's a set of rules for how a program interacts with the operating system. It defines how a program is stored on disk to be runnable by the operating system, how to do system calls, how to link with libraries, etc. But for being able to link to libraries for example, your program and the library have to agree on how to make function calls between your program an the library (and vice versa) and to be able to make function calls both the program and the library have to have the same idea of stack layout, register usage, function call conventions, etc. And for function calls you need to agree on what the parameters mean and that includes sizes, alignment and signedness of types.

Comment: ABI contains also calling conventions, that is a set of rules of how the program calls functions. It also contains constraints dictated by the processor (e.g. alignment constraints for various primitive data types)

Comment: There is no requirement that a compiler support any means by which a program can interact with anything in the outside world without going through library functions that are bundled with the compiler.  Nothing would forbid an implementation targeting x64 from using a 36-bit ones'-complement integer type (performing whatever shifts and masking operations would be needed to emulate that).  Such an implementation could be genuinely useful if someone had some Univac code they wanted to run but they didn't have a working 36-bit system.

Comment: @supercat I never said there were requirements like that. I just described reality as it is.

Comment: Upvoted because it gives the "very grounded in practical reality" angle.

Comment: @supercat While there's no requirement in ISO that the program be able to interact with th eoutside world, I think the point is that this is realistically going to be *the* major influencing factor in why the compiler chooses the sizes it does, in the same way that while an x64 compiler *could* provide 19-bit `char` and 41-bit `int`s padded to 57... but they won't, unless writing an emulator or an undefined-behaviour-brutalizer.

Comment: This is plain wrong.  It is utterly the compiler.  The compiler  may well choose a size that works well with the processor and the operating system, but that is completely the compiler's decision.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, using that argument it's not the compiler, it's you. Because you have the choice of compilers. Except, maybe there's no free will, then it is the universe the chooses. The big bang set up the parameters  that led you to choosing a compiler which was written by people whose parameters made them choose certain sizes for types. On the other hand, in reality where I live we have compilers that interact with their environment in useful ways and people don't waste their time building useless compilers but some still waste their time arguing that it could be done.

Comment: Actual right answer, thank God. Might be worth admitting that some ABIs have allowed a choice of "memory models" with different sized pointers, data layouts (especially on RISC processors where loading a bigger pointer takes extra instructions, and/or there are special addressing modes with smaller offsets that are more efficient).

Comment: @MartinBonner Art has it right, compilers are generally implemented following a standard ABI. That ABI design will be very much constrained by the processor design, and some ABIs are designed by the CPU creators, although some are OS-specific.

Comment: @WillCrawford There is a lot of x64 compilers for Windows that use some made-up ABI which is completely different from the Windows x64 calling convention. Because they decided to bring in the whole package of Linux ABI, and did exactly just that.

Comment: ... a mistake which people have been fixing, slowly, ever since ;o)

Comment: @Leushenko: Before C went off the rails, I'd been hoping that compilers could evolve in the direction of allowing both "compiler-convenience" data types and guaranteed-format data types.  It find it ironic that one of the advantages of C in the early days was that one could use structures for data format conversions on machines whose data types matched requirements, but rather than evolving in the direction of letting programmers write portable code by telling the compiler what layout they needed, compilers have evolved in the direction of requiring programmers to byte-parse everything...

Comment: ...unless they disable optimizations wholesale.

Comment: To be pedantic, ABI is the Application Binary Interface, and that by itself doesn’t constrain the sizes of types at all. If all you care about is being able to link to the ABI, you could just change the headers to replace all `int` declarations with `int32_t`. They’ll link to libraries compiled with the existing ABI just fine. The actual constraint in practice is that a drop-in replacement for the old compiler needs to be compatible with existing source code, with all its implicit assumptions.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You totally could write a fork of gcc that follows a different calling convention. It wouldn’t be able to link to the system libraries—but it could make its own runtime library and stick it in a different directory. Then it can’t link other libraries unless they follow your new conventions—so, recompile them against your own runtime and put the new versions in the same directory, *And this has been done several times.* @Joker_vD gave one example, and the x32 alternative ABI on Linux is another.

Comment: @WillCrawford The point wasn’t that it was a good idea or a bad idea; the point was that it’s been done, so it must be possible. (At least if you only care about FOSS libraries.)

Answer (score 8):

It is strictly, 100%, entirely the compiler that decides the value of sizeof(int). It is not a combination of the system and the compiler. It is just the compiler (and the C/C++ language specifications).

If you develop iPad or iPhone apps you do the compiler runs on your Mac. The Mac and the iPhone/iPac use different processors. Nothing about your Mac tells the compiler what size should be used for int on the iPad.

Comment: If you meant to oppose [Art's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48921713/673852), then you're overdoing it. I suppose his answer referred to the target system, not the host on which the cross-compiler runs, while you're talking about host system, which, of course, is irrelevant to sizes of data types on the target.

Comment: This simply isn't true. At least you admit to the "language specifications", but every system has a standard (ABI) for what size the default "int" is, how parameters are passed to functions, etc... e.g. for iOS apps, [this Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html) spells it out:

Comment: (quote) *When different pieces of code must work together, they must follow standard agreed-upon conventions about how code should act. Conventions include the size and format of common data types, as well as the instructions used when one piece of code calls another. **Compilers are implemented based on these conventions** so that they can emit binary code that works together. Collectively, these conventions are referred to as an application binary interface (ABI).*

Comment: Again, the compiler decides whether to follow that convention. And "ABI" is merely a buzzword acronym. Decades ago, we referred to that as a "calling convention." These calling conventions dictate nothing to the compiler. The compiler should follow them but this is not always the case. Witness the C versus Pascal calling conventions windoze developers had to deal with.

Comment: Note: They changed their COMPILERS. It was a choice, not a requirement imposed by the system.

Comment: Everything is a choice (including following the ANSI C standards, many compilers don't by default), every choice has a price. If you put the work in it is absoloutely possible to build a C compiler that ignores the standard conventions of the platform it targets (note: not nessacerally the same as the platform it runs on) and to wrap or reimplement all the standard library functions to make them compatible with your compiler. Just because you can do something though doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

The processor designer determines what registers and instructions are available, what the alignment rules for efficient access are, how big memory addresses are and so-on.

The C standard sets minimum requirements for the built-in types. "char" must be at least 8 bit, "short" and "int" must be at least 16 bit, "long" must be at least 32 bit and "long long" must be at least 64 bit. It also says that "char" must be equivilent to the smallest unit of memory the program can address and that the size ordering of the standard types must be maintained.

Other standards may also have an impact. For example version 2 of the "single Unix specification" says that int must be at least 32-bits.

Finally existing code has an impact. Porting is hard enough already, noone wants to make it any harder than they have to.

---

When porting an OS and compiler to a new CPU someone has to define what is known of as a "C ABI". This defines how binary code talks to each other including.

- The size and alignment requirements of the built-in types.
- The packing rules for structures (and hence what their size will be).
- How parameters are passed and returned
- How the stack is managed

In general once and ABI is defined for a combination of CPU family and OS it doesn't change much (sometimes the size of more obscure types like "long double" changes). Changing it brings a bunch of breakage for relatively little gain.

Similarly those porting an OS to a platform with similar characteristics to an existing one will usually choose the same sizes as on previous platforms that the OS was ported to.

---

In practice OS/compiler vendors typically settle on one of a few combinations of sizes for the basic integer types.

- "LP32": char is 8 bits. short and int are 16 bits, long and pointer are 32-bits. Commonly used on 8 bit and 16 bit platforms.
- "ILP32": char is 8 bits, short is 16 bits. int, long and pointer are all 32 bits. If long long exists it is 64 bit. Commonly used on 32 bit platforms.
- "LLP64": char is 8 bits. short is 16 bits. int and long are 32 bits. long long and pointer are 64 bits. Used on 64 bit windows.
- "LP64": char is 8 bits. short is 16 bits. int is 32 bits. long, long long and pointer are 64 bits. Used on most 64-bit unix-like systems.
- "ILP64": char is 8 bits, short is 16 bits, int, long and pointer and long long are all 64  bits. Apparently used on some early 64-bit operating systems but rarely seen nowadays.

---

64 bit processors can typically run both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. Generally this is handled by having a compatibility layer in your OS. So your 32-bit binary uses the same data types it would use when running on a 32-bit system, then the compatibility layer translates the system calls so that the 64-bit OS can handle them.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler decides how large the basic types are, and what the layout of structures is.  If a library declares any types, it will decide how those are defined and therefore what size they are.

However, it is often the case that compatibility with an existing standard, and the need to link to existing libraries produced by other compilers, forces a given implementation to make certain choices.  For example, the language standard says that a `wchar_t` has to be wider than 16 bits, and on Linux, it is 32 bits wide, but it’s always been 16 bits on Windows, so compilers for Windows all choose to be compatible with the Windows API instead of the language standard.  A lot of legacy code for both Linux and Windows assumes that a `long` is exactly 32 bits wide, while other code assumed it was wide enough to hold a timestamp in seconds or an IPv4 address or a file offset or the bits of a pointer, and (after one compiler defined `int` as 64 bits wide and `long` as 32 bits wide) the language standard made a new rule that `int` cannot be wider than `long`.

As a result, mainstream compilers from this century choose to define `int` as 32 bits wide, but historically some have defined it as 16 bits, 18 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits and other sizes.  Some compilers let you choose whether `long` will be exactly 32 bits wide, as some legacy code assumes, or as wide as a pointer, as other legacy code assumes.

This demonstrates how assumptions you make today, like some type always being 32 bits wide, might come back to bite you in the future.  This has already happened to C codebases twice, in the transitions to 32-bit and 64-bit code.

But what should you actually *use*?

The `int` type is rarely useful these days.  There’s usually some other type you can use that makes a stronger guarantee of what you’ll get.  (It does have one advantage: types that aren’t as wide as an `int` could get automatically widened to `int`, which could cause a few really weird bugs when you mix signed and unsigned types, and `int` is the smallest type guaranteed not to be shorter than `int`.)

If you’re using a particular API, you’ll generally want to use the same type it does.  There are numerous types in the standard library for specific purposes, such as `clock_t` for clock ticks and `time_t` for time in seconds.

If you want the fastest type that’s at least 16 bits wide, that’s `int_fast16_t`, and there are other similar types.  (Unless otherwise specified, all these types are defined in `<stdint.h>`.)  If you want the smallest type that’s at least 32 bits wide, to pack the most data into your arrays, that’s `int_least32_t`.  If you want the widest possible type, that’s `intmax_t`.  If you know you want exactly 32 bits, *and your compiler has a type like that*, it’s `int32_t` If you want something that’s 32 bits wide on a 32-bit machine and 64 bits wide on a 64-bit machine, and always the right size to store a pointer, that’s `intptr_t`.  If you want a good type for doing array indexing and pointer math, that’s `ptrdiff_t` from `<stddef.h>`.  (This one’s in a different header because it’s from C89, not C99.)

Use the type you really mean!

Comment: "the language standard says that a `wchar_t` has to be wider than 16 bits" -- chapter and verse? I'm pretty sure it doesn't say that, in any version, at least not *explicitly*. The ambiguity in the standard about how wide it was *really* supposed to be is why `char16_t` and `char32_t` were introduced.

Comment: The standard doesn't say that wchar_t has to be wider than 8 bits, nor does it specify what character set is used (a system could in principle use 16 bit wchar for a locale-specific East Asian codepage, for example, or *only* support the BMP), but it's pretty clear that using variable length or stateful encodings isn't acceptable.

Comment: @Random832 The standard says that `wchar_t` is “an integer type whose range of values can represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended character set specified among the supported locales.” You are correct in the sense that a given implementation does not have to provide any locale that supports Unicode—or even ASCII. However, the standard *does* require support for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UCS-32 strings and a `char32_t` type. If you want to be compatible with Microsoft’s locales: `setlocale(".1200");` alone requires support for all of Unicode. And the Windows API requires UTF-16.

Comment: @Random832 So, any mainstream implementation has to support at least one Unicode locale to even be compatible with the OS, and being able to compile apps that work with Unicode is a *de facto* requirement in 2018. In theory, that would mean `wchar_t` on a Windows compiler has to be wide enough to store at least 1,112,064 distinct values, and therefore must be at least 21 bits wide. In practice, Microsoft defined `wchar_t` as 16 bits wide in the last century, changed it from UCS-2 to UTF-16, and refuses to break everything. So everyone who uses the Windows API does too.

Comment: I think you're making it sound like the compiler is a poor, oppressed minority being bullied by the language standards ;o). Seriously, though, the processor architecture has a big influence on e.g. minimum alignment requirements for a type, such as whether a 64 bit integer needs to be aligned to a "64 bit boundary", or 32, or maybe not at all; and ABI standards exist for a reason (so you have a hope in heck of inter-operability). It might be that the first compiler on a system ends up defining the ABI, but it's still very constrained in what decisions it can make.

Comment: @WillCrawford I’m not sure exactly what you’re disagreeing with—as I said, the language standard itself only says that `int` must be at least 16 bits wide, at least as wide as `short` and no wider than `long`, and I gave an extended example of a type definition that directly violates the language standard for compatibility with the OS API. In practice, though, `int` is generally constrained by the system libraries, by the need to support legacy code, or both. Any compiler that can choose freely basically has to choose which decades-old code it will break.

Comment: I felt the way you described it made it sound like “the compiler” was the arbiter of all, and that's not really the whole picture … I tried to be humorous about it because I can see you’ve worked hard to produce a well-written answer(!). It's partly the fault of the question - it doesn't mention ABIs at all and asks for a binary choice, so your answer is certainly not “completely wrong”.

Comment: @WillCrawford I’ve edited a bit, to I hope be a little clearer about the constraints compiler implementers face.

Comment: @WillCrawford Even before the latest edit, I did give the example of `wchar_t` as a type defined for compatibility with the API. (Technically, if the ABI were what mattered, it could just have made programmers use `char16_t*` and still be able to link with other libraries, and redefined `wchar_t` as `char32_t`.) But I hope there’s no ambiguity now.

Comment: It's better (and wasn't *bad* before). I wish you and @Art could combine forces :o)

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about the compiler, you mush have a clean image about `build|host|target`, i.e, the machine you are building on (build), the machine that you are building for (host), and the machine that GCC will produce code for (target), because for "cross compiling" is very different from "native compiling".

About the question "who decide the sizeof datatype and structure", it depends on the target system you told compiler to build binary for. If target is 64 bits, the compiler will translate sizeof(long) to 8, and if the target is a 32 bits machine, the compiler will translate sizeof(long) to 4. All these have been predefined  by header file you used to build your program. If you read your `$MAKETOP/usr/include/stdint.h', there are typedefs to define the size of your datatype.

To avoid the error created by the size difference, [Google coding style-Integer_Types](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types) recommend using types like int16_t, uint32_t, int64_t, etc. Those were defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Above is only those `Plain Old Data', such as int. If you talk about a structure, there is another story, because the size of a structure depends on [packing alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c), the boundaries alignment for each field in the structure, which will have impact on the size of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It's the compiler, and more precisely its code generator component.

Of course, the compiler is architecture-aware and makes choices that fit with it.

In some cases, the work is performed in two passes, one at compile-time by an intermediate code generators, then a second at run-time by a just-in-time compiler. But this is still a compiler.