# R Markdown - Do Not Display Text in HTML Output

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to not display 'text' (not code) in an R markdown when it is output to HTML? For example:

````
```{r, echo=False}
I want the output of this R Code
```
````

This is text to introduce the next section in the .Rmd file. I, however, do NOT want this to appear in my .HTML file.

````
```{r, echo=False}
Next section of R code to display
```
````

Comment: Code in the `\`\`\`{...}` needs to be R code, so `echo=FALSE`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown) previous question may be helpful.

Comment: I think something like `include=FALSE, echo=FALSE` will allow it to execute but have none of its output rendered into the document. If that isn't what you mean, please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

whatever you don't want to show in output, put it between
<!---
blabla
-->

For example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
I want the output of this R Code```

<!---
This is text to introduce the next section in the .Rmd file. I, however, do NOT want this to appear in my .HTML file.
-->

```{r, echo=FALSE}
Next section of R code to display```
````

Comment: That's not what I was saying. The OP is using mixed-case `=False`, and I think (without verifying at the moment) that the assignments in there need to be proper R expressions, so change to upper-case `=FALSE`.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your point. You are absolutely right :)