# Embed link in (html) comment block in Markdown

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way we can embed hyperlink into the comment section of a (github) markdown file?

Example usage:

```html
<!-- Please read the code of conduct before submitting, [code_of_conduct](https://link.to.code_of_conduct) -->
```

Comment: What effect would embedding a link in a comment have since the comment doesn't render?

Comment: e.g. when you are editing a pull request and there are commented code of conduct link that if possible you can directly click on it instead of copy/paste. Plus, you can put relative path instead of absolute path and let the parser figure it out so you are better future-proof for changes. Overall, I think there are many use cases once you introduce comments into markdowns as now they do convey information to the client users even if not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

After testing various [comment markdown syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4823468/6309), using GitHub web editor, none of them are rendered as "clickable links"

For instance, `[ https://google.com ]::`, when editable, is still rendered as text, to be copy-pasted if you need to access its URL.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to put a break before the command. I just had the same issue and this works for me on Github.

Random text "enter"

"[code_of_conduct]""(https://link.to.code_of_conduct)" "enter"
Random text