# How to make Comments in Julia Markdown

Tags: julia, markdown

In this great [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823468/comments-in-markdown) I read about making comments in Markdown. I would like to use this to visually structure my `jmd` document:

```
---
title: My Title
output: pdf_document
---

[\\]: # (###########################################)
[\\]: # (Title Page)
[\\]: # (###########################################)

Some text here.
```

I can `weave` this document and get the correct output, but I get warnings

```
[WARNING] Duplicate link reference '[\\]' at line 8 column 1
[WARNING] Duplicate link reference '[\\]' at line 9 column 1
```

which I would prefer to avoid.

How can I comment in Julia Markdown without getting warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
<!-- ###################################################### -->
<!-- ####### Title Page                                     -->
<!-- ###################################################### -->
```

Honestly, I liked the option from the question better, because it is technically a link and therefore in VSCode displayed much better, but you can't have everything, I guess.