# Which Language / Syntax / MarkUp is this?

Tags: markdown, github-copilot

While writing a README in one of my projects, GitHub Co-Pilot suggested a piece of code that I don't understand. It seems to be some mark-up of some sort.

Does anyone know what it means?

```
[//]: # ( Language: markdown
[//]: # ( Path: cmd/web/README.md
```

Context:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this is a way of adding comments in Markdown.

It has been well explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885980/2370679