# How can I write two separate blockquotes in sequence using markdown?

Tags: syntax, markdown

I need to place two blockquotes in sequence, however markdown combines them into a single blockquote. The only way I can get them to separate is placing some junk text between them. As this textfield allows me to use Markdown I can demonstrate:

```markdown
> First Quote

> Second Quote
```

Results in:

> First Quote
>
> Second Quote

While using junk text:

```markdown
> First Quote

.   
> Second Quote
```

Results in:

> First Quote

.

> Second Quote

**I cannot use HTML tags or HTML entities. Only Markdown.**

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Stack Overflow [conversion to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) made it so that the space in between causes two separate blockquotes, whereas its previous rendering did not.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can separate blockquotes without html elements by using comment markup `<!-- -->` with an extra whiteline between the blocks:

```markdown
> Imagination is more important than knowledge.

<!-- -->
>  Never think of the future. It comes soon enough.

<!-- -->
> Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new.
```

Of course you can use any HTML elements you like as well (as noted by @pepoloan):

```markdown
> Imagination is more important than knowledge.

<div></div>
>  Never think of the future. It comes soon enough.

<div></div>
> Anyone who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new.
```

Comment: I myself prefer using `<div></div>` tag pairs, because I can easily set the distance between the blocks.

Comment: @pepoluan Why wouldn't you just use `margin-bottom` on the `<blockquote>`?

Comment: Because, the `<blockquote>` as generated by the Markdown parser is usually not easily editable to add `class` attribute. Inserting explicit HTML tags enables me to inline the stylesheet, e.g. `<div style="margin-bottom:200px;"></div>`. Had I been writing the webpage completely in HTML, I'd leverage `class` attributes, of course :)

Comment: @pepoluan I'd wrap any markdown content in a classed container and use it as a hook to target its contents. Much better imho than littering your html with unsemantic, empty elements.

Comment: Again, that depends on the situation: Can you actually do that with the parser you use? I know some blogging engines allow authors to create pages completely in Markdown, and do an on-the-fly transform of the Markdown into HTML. In such cases, it will be difficult to change the engine's mechanisms.

Comment: @pepoluan I guess there are some very restrictive setups out there. Can't say it's ever been a problem for me though.

Answer (score 21):

An empty header, `#`, followed by a space also works.

```markdown
> Hello World

# 

> Goodbye world
```

Unfortunately it isn't much better than `<!-- -->` But I kind of like it more, and use it.

Comment: I've found this works in places where an html comment does not, probably because it's a markdown solution and not html.

Comment: Yeah, I come from SimpleNote and the `<!-- -->` tricks works for the web, but not in the iOS app. This works too!. Give it a try if the accepted solution doesn't work for you either.

Answer (score 12):

>If I try a non breaking space

&nbsp;

>it line breaks; don't ask me how

Result:

> If I try a non breaking space

> it line breaks; don't ask me how

Comment: As I mention in my question; 'I cannot use HTML tags. Only Markdown.'

Comment: Unfortunately a non-breaking-space doesn't break the blockquote as it is non-breaking ;)

Comment: This looks to work on reddit, the blank line before the nbsp is important.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Use a U+200B character in-between the quotes, which is defined as a zero-length space to break up the quotes.

```
> Quote

​

> Quote
```

It looks like this:

> > Quote

​

> > Quote

Comment: That's nice, but It's too confusing in the context I'm using it. The text has to be edited by someone not well versed in markup. I can't see them being able to use this successfully.

Comment: Ahh... I thought you were talking about this site in general.  I would say HTML markup would be best, but you cannot use that.  With that, you need to do something that is not a space, but not visible to the user (which is why the zero-length space may work)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which parses your original input as two consecutive blockquotes.

Answer (score 0):

From experimenting, I found these to work also. Note they are not legal HTML or Markdown, but they seem do to the job:

```
<!

<$

</

<a
```

Comment: I wonder if they are implementation dependent.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do so is by just adding `</>` after first blockquote followed by a newline. And by this way nothing gets printed as well.

> First quote

> Second Quote

Comment: Please read the question properly: 'I cannot use HTML tags or HTML entities. Only Markdown.' A </> is an HTML tag.

Answer (score -2):

You have something like your first block quote, then 2 enters and  on the second enter give a `#` symbol for Heading but leave the  heading blank and  then you next quote in next line.

> This is one quote

> This is another quote

Comment: This is a duplication of another answer.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. I have posted another answer. Please feel free to check that and comment on it. Please vote to that answer.

Comment: I will keep such things in check and post answers accordingly. Thank you for your correction.